# an infinite sum with binomials

Tags: calculus, summation

I've got a new exercise.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k}
$$
I've tried this: 
$$
(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^{n-k}x^k
$$
Substitute 
$$
x=x^{n2^n}
$$
And integrate from 0 to 1 with respect to x.
$$
\int_0^1(1+x^{n2^n})^n = 1+\frac{1}{n2^n+1}\binom{n}{1}+\frac{1}{n2^n+2}\binom{n}{2}+...++\frac{1}{n2^n+n}\binom{n}{n} | -1+\frac{1}{n2^n}
$$

$$ 
\int_0^1(1+x^{n2^n})^n  -1+\frac{1}{n2^n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k}
$$
And from here i have no idea!Thank you for your time!

Comment: You unfortunately have a wrong implementation of a good idea. For $n \ge 1$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^{n2^n - 1}(1+x)^n dx &= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^{n2^n + k - 1} dx =  \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \left. \frac{x^{n2^n + k}}{n2^n + k} \right|^1_0=  \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{1}{n2^n + k} \; .
\end{align}
$$

The form of the integral is reminescent of the definition of the beta function.

Comment: If you are interested in the limit of this expression: [Limit of sum of terms containing binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1657124).